# How to make a dataframe from graph object?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, nodes, igraph

I have a large, 266 vertices directed graph. I want to break up some of the paths so I can run a t-test or ANOVA between two of the paths using data that makes up their attributes. The trouble is I want to work with the edge attributes, specifically. I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Each path that I'm looking at has 20 or 21 vertices, so I'm also thinking of using a repeated-measures test.

Let's use this:

```
inst2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
motherinst2 = c(7, 8, 2, 10, 11) 
km = c(20, 30, 40, 25, 60)
df2 = data.frame(inst2, motherinst2)
df2 = cbind(df2, km)
g2 = graph_from_data_frame(df2)
tkplot(g2)
```

Let's say I want to make a dataframe that has 5-10 and 8-3 as the data frame, with their edge attributes (km) as values going down the rows.

So it's like:

```
       5-10      3-8

 1       30       25
```

How can I do this? Is there a way where I can just specify my root nodes and make a dataframe based on that alone? Even if it's two separate ones...then I can just cbind later.

Comment: How did you get your expected output from your sample data? I assume `5-10` and `3-8` are the edges. What about the other edges from your sample data? Where do the values come from for the two links in your expected output?

Comment: I made the reproducible data up. 5-10 indicates a path that I want isolated to make a data frame of its edges. 30 and 22.1would be examples of values stored as attributes in the edges along those paths. Pretend that they are longer.

I can't make reproducible data up that matches what I'm actually working with. It's too complicated and stems from an edgelist and has 266 observations.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it's actually *not* reproducible data. Your expected output does *not* match the sample data? Is that correct?

Comment: The desired output matches the data I have put into my question, but it is not the same data as the data I am actually working with. Just a representation.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I've also noticed that you changed your expected output now to match your input data. Previously, you had two rows in your expected output.

Comment: Yes, I decided it may have been confusing others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually have to convert it to a graph beforehand. You can use 
`expand.grid` to get all possible combinations of edges to test against each other.

```
start <- 1
end <- 2
df3 <- df3[df3$isnt2 %in% c(start, end) | df3$motherinst2 %in% c(start, end),]
ind <- expand.grid(1:nrow(df2), 1:nrow(df2))
df3 <- data.frame(df2[ind[[1]], ], df2[ind[[2]], ])
```

Now you can subset to your desired start and end nodes for testing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having trouble getting this though. If I know which observation numbers of the root and terminal vertices I want to make data frames from, how would I make data frames from those using your code? That is to say, if I know a start and end point, how can I make a dataframe that uses the attributes of every single edge between those points?

Comment: I'm not totally following your process here, but are you staying the following. If startt point or end point in from node or in to node keep those edges?

Comment: Yes, essentially that is the case. Like, stating a node as a starting point, and then another as an end point, and then taking all edge attributes between those points and storing them in a dataframe.

Comment: I've updated my answer above with the ability to subset to desired start and end nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
inst2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
motherinst2 = c(7, 8, 2, 10, 11)
km = c(20, 30, 40, 25, 60)
df2 = data.frame(inst2, motherinst2)
df2 = cbind(df2, km)

require(igraph);
g2 = graph_from_data_frame(df2)
```

Let's start from the `igraph` object named `g2`.

```
# Store as dataframe
df <- with(as_data_frame(g2), setNames(rbind.data.frame(km), paste(from, to, sep = "-")))
df;
#  2-7 3-8 4-2 5-10 6-11
#1  20  30  40   25   60
```

Note, considering that you started from a `dataframe`, you can also do directly:

```
df <- with(df2, setNames(rbind.data.frame(km), paste(inst2, motherinst2, sep = "-")))
```

Comment: Yes! Sort of. Is there a way of isolating only certain paths of the graph that make it into the dataframe? i.e., just 3-8 or 4-2, for example?

Comment: @hmnoidk `df[names(df) %in% c("3-8", "4-2")]`?